# Importar contenido a wordpress - problemas

Tags: wordpress

puede que esta pregunta sea muy simple para muchos, pero tengo un problema, normal mente trabajo con wordpress, hay temas que vienen con un boton de importar paginas de ejemplo y ya esta,  pero hay otros que vienen con la siguiente estructura
[image: carpetas de tema]

viene el tema y otras carpetas por separado, al instalarlo el tema se instala pero como se imaginaran viene vacion, sin paginas de ejemplo ni nada de diseño, veo que siempre esta esa carpeta SampleDada, que trae unos archivos .json, desconosco como importar eso o donde pegarlo, ese es el problema, me pueden ayudar.
gracias

Comment: De verdad no entiendo que deseas hacer?

Comment: hola, es importar el contenido de ejemplo. cuando instalamos un wordpress viene vacio, hay temas que traen paginas y estilos de ejemplo, dependiendo el tema hay algunos que importan el contenido oprimiendo un boton dentro de wordpress, y en mi caso este wordpress tiene el "sampledata" por fuera (la carpeta posee archivos php), las instrucciones dicen que debi importar esos archivos para tener las paginas de ejemplo, pero no se como hacerlo, gracias, (la forma de hacerlo, ya que no hay ningun boton de importar)